# How to use date-time utils in libGdx?

Tags: date, datetime, time, libgdx, format

I want to use DateTime formatting in my libGdx application, and I want to to be compatible with the web version (gwt). The default java way is not working with the gwt version as the classes needed are not supported.

I already tried using external libraries like [joda-time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), and [treeten-bp](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/). The latter has dependencies to java classes not supported in gwt, and [joda-time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) has dependencies that I could not resolve...

I've seen that gwt has time utils that I need, but I wasn't able to figure out how to use them.

Or even how to add some logic to use normal java utils in android and desktop, and use gwt classes in html5/gwt. But I just can't figure out how to use the gwt classes ie. [DateTimeFormat](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/DateTimeFormat.html) in libGdx. Trying to just import it results in `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/core/client/GWTBridge`

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an ActionResolver and implement for each of your module the DateTime method you wish you use (See https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code for how to write platform specific code).

For Android, iOS and Desktop implementation you can use SimpleDateFormat in you ActionResolver.

For the HTML module, you can use the library

```
com.google.gwt.i18n.client.DateTimeFormat
```

and implement as follow

```
    public class HtmlLauncher extends GwtApplication implements com.yourpackage.util.ActionResolver{

        @Override
        public GwtApplicationConfiguration getConfig () {
                return new GwtApplicationConfiguration(360, 640);
        }

        @Override
        public ApplicationListener getApplicationListener () {
                return new MyGame(this);
        }

        @Override
        public String convertDate(String format, Date date) {
            DefaultDateTimeFormatInfo info = new DefaultDateTimeFormatInfo();
            DateTimeFormat dateFormat = new DateTimeFormat(format, info) {}; 

            return dateFormat.format(date);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I know I've read about this method somewhere.. It just didn't click in my head that this is just what I needed.

Comment: Found it: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code